# Storing a table with multiple value data in custom metadata types

Tags: picklist, data, custom-metadata

I have a table with two columns. One column is a role and the other are keywords associated with that role. For example:

| Roles | Keywords |
| --- | --- |
| Admin | Desk, Forms, Data Entry |
| HR | People, Communication |

What is the best way to store this data in custom metadata types in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [metadata relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_relationships_create.htm&type=5).

Keep Role metadata as parent. And RoleChild as a child relationship metadata.

Just like a parent child relationship.
So when you see admin, it will display all RoleChild under it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. And would it be the case of creating a new record for each keyword or is there a way to have a sort of picklist of each set of values?

Comment: I didnt understand the ask in your comment.

Comment: It's okay. Each keyword will need its own record and linked to the parent record for the role. Thanks